# non-printable character not recognised as field separator

Tags: shell, unix, awk, aix

I have a file. Its field separator is non-printable character `\x1c` (`chr(28)` in Python). In VI it looks like `a^\b^\c` but using `cat` I just see `abc`. The fieldseparator `^\` is not seen.

I have a simple awk command:

```
awk -F $’\x1c’ ‘{print NF}’ a
```

to get the total number of fields. It works on MacOS, but on AIX, it fails. It seems AIX can't recognize the field separator. So the output is `1` meaning the whole line is considered one field.
How to do this on AIX? Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: Create test.py to prepare the data

Comment: Python code : print( ‘a’+chr(28)+’b’+chr(28)+’c’

Comment: It's not `awk`-specific; use `bash` instead of the default AIX-shell (`ksh`). Or use `printf` like this: `FldSep=$(printf '\034'); awk -F "$FldSep" ...`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I must use ksh。 thankyou your second way works. One thing I dont understand. you use \034 . is it octal number？I tried FldSep=$（printf ‘\xc1’ ）； why doesnt work？

Comment: Have you try to use gawk (if installed) in AIX?

Comment: @RomeoNinov no gawk installed..

Comment: Yes, it is octal -- some platforms don't support hex (`printf '\x1c'`) but every platform supports octal (`printf '\034'`)

Comment: Perl is the way to go for *"troublesome"* operating systems like SunOS, Solaris and AIX. It is far more consistent across platforms than many other tools.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thanks a lot ！

Comment: @MarkSetchell good to know that

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this on SOLARIS running ksh.

```
sol bash $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | cat -v
^\a^\b^\c$
sol bash $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk -F$'\x1c' '{print NF}'
4
sol bash $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk -F$'\034' '{print NF}'
4

sol ksh $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | cat -v
^\a^\b^\c$
sol ksh $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk -F$'\x1c' '{print NF}'
1
sol ksh $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk -F$'\034' '{print NF}'
1
```

I cannot confirm if this is a ksh issue or awk issue, as other cases fail on both.

```
sol ksh/bash $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\034"}{print NF}'
1
```

All the above cases work successfully on any Linux system (which run by default GNU awk), but it seemed to have failed gloriously.

The following trick is a work arround that cannot fail at all (until the point it will fail):

```
sol ksh/bash $ printf '\034a\034b\034c' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=sprintf("%c",28)}{print NF}'
4
```

The above works because we let awk set the FS using the `sprintf` function where we pass the decimal number `28=x1c=034`

Answer (score 1):

Well `$'\x1c'` is a *bashizm,* the portable format is `"$(printf '\034')"`.

(This answer has already been written as a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

When `awk` has issues, try Perl

```
$ cat -vT tonyren.txt
a^\b^\c^\d
p^\q^\r^\s
x^\y^\z

$ perl -F"\x1c" -le ' { print scalar @F } ' tonyren.txt
4
4
3

$
```

Comment: can you add ````hexdump file````

Comment: No, awk does not `sometimes break portability`. awk has versions, just like perl does, and version-specific extensions only work in the specified versions, that's all. If you write POSIX awk code then it'll work in any POSIX compliant awk which is most of them and it has the benefit that every UNIX installation comes with awk installed while only some have perl.

Comment: For this question, I don't think it has version specific problem in awk.. may be I'll rephrase it. As Marck Setchell mentioned in his comments, Perl is the way for such cases..Perl comes with all *nix flavors and in Enterprise editions, installing CPAN modules may be disabled.